# Android - SQLite database not updating row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have looked at the plethora of similar topics for the past couple days but none seem to help my actual situation or maybe it's just my inexperience.

I have a simple application that performs CRUD operations. I can successfully enter new rows into the table as well as delete them, however something is wrong with my update code and I can't find why. What has me puzzled is it worked once, then never did again regardless if I create new entries or delete the database entirely and start again. Isolating what I think the relevant code would be the operation flow is as follows.

The individual items are inside a RecyclerView and are sent from an inner class to the activity to be edited and updated:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String contactName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
        final int contactNumber = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER));
        final String contactMail = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL));
        final int currentPosition = position;

    holder.mEditContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ContactUpdate.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CONTACT_POSITION, currentPosition);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, contactName);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE, contactNumber);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MAIL, contactMail);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Then I get them in the retrieving class and organise the values into the appropriate EditText views. I'm sure there is a more efficient way but I'm still learning:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        mPosition = intent.getIntExtra(ContactRecyclerAdapter.CONTACT_POSITION, 0);
        mContactName = intent.getStringExtra(ContactRecyclerAdapter.EXTRA_NAME);
        mContactPhone = intent.getIntExtra(ContactRecyclerAdapter.EXTRA_PHONE, 0);
        mContactMail = intent.getStringExtra(ContactRecyclerAdapter.EXTRA_MAIL);

        mUpdateName.setText(mContactName);
        mUpdatePhone.setText("" + mContactPhone);
        mUpdateMail.setText(mContactMail);
```

Lastly my method to update the row:

```
private void updateData() {

        String name = mUpdateName.getText().toString();
        String getPhone = mUpdatePhone.getText().toString();
        int phone = Integer.parseInt(getPhone);
        String mail = mUpdateMail.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = new ContactOpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactEntry._ID, mPosition);
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER, phone);
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL, mail);

        String selection = ContactEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";

        String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(mPosition)};

        db.update(ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        db.close();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactList.class));
    }
```

What is happening is the row is not being updated. Currently I have three mock entries entered. I put a break point at the `update()` line to try and find out what is happening. The original name for the this entry is "ted" and it's the third in the list. If I edit the EditText field and run the `updateData()` method, when the break point is hit it correctly shows the edited value as well the correct position of 2. However the database doesn't actually update. I am clearly misunderstanding how something works here.

To avoid bloat I have only included what I think is pertinent, but if anymore info is required then I'm happy to add.

Lastly here is a screen shot of the debugger at the break point showing what I perceive to be the correct information and where I'm completely confused as to why it is not working (I added a bunch of g's on the end of the name "ted" just to test if it would work).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this particular problem and the answer was quite simple and a little embarrassing. I was trying to use the cursor position for the row ID not realising that the database isn't using a zero-base index like the cursor, hence the primary key was not matching.

As I am using a RecyclerView I added the following line to my onBindViewHolder and passed the variable to my update activity which then could be used in the selectionArgs

```
final long id = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry._ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Chnage your call to update as below

```
 int count = db.update(ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
```

where count shows the number of the rows afftected with the update function, this would help you know exactly if there was any updated row or not.

Note :-We use like when, sometimes, you don’t know exactly the complete keyword that you want to query. For example, you may know that your most favorite song contains the word,elevator but you don’t know exactly the name.
If you know the exact value try to use:-

```
String selection = ContactEntry._ID + " =? ";
```

Comment: That's for the clarification between LIKE ? and = ?, that makes a lot of sense. Where would I use the variable int count? I have tried assigning it to a placeholder to see what it returns and it's not returning anything. Unfortunately even after editing the selection string to your suggestion it still isn't updating so I must have broken something earlier in the chain and will try some other things.

Comment: You can use the count variable to , to make your fuction return true if it is >0 for else false otherwise. And can use the returned value for moving forward if your call was successful or doing something it other case.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely making some progress. If I've understood correctly (sorry, still learning!) I updated the method from returning void to returning an int. I set a break at the return at the end to see what is happening and count is returning 0. Out of interest I removed my where clause and args and it returned 4, one for each line which it then updated every row in that column. I'm guessing something is wrong with my where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
String selection = ContactEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";

String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(mPosition)};
```

Update this above code to this below code

```
String selection = ContactEntry._ID + " = ?";

String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(mPosition)};
```

You want to update an exact row. But 'LIKE' keyword mostly uses for searches.

Besides, You are opening your activity when you update your data. Update or insert in database takes some time. When your next activity start, database may not finish its write operation. It could lead you to see the previous data. Make sure your database is updated and then update the view.

See your database from emulator that database has the new value or not. Then do the further work.

Comment: Thank you for differentiating between LIKE ? and = ?. Unfortunately it is still not updating. I understand what you mean about starting the next activity possibly too soon. To test I removed the intent to start the next activity and opened the .db in  DB Browser for SQLite and the row was not updated. I suspect I have messed up passing the position to the update activity despite returning the value I think is right. That's all I can think of for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete you _Id from contentValues:

```
//values.put(ContactEntry._ID, mPosition);
```

I think you can't change PRIMARY_KEY, you say what line you want to update in:

```
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(mPosition)};
```